# How to check if condition for previous page url in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am working with Angular and I almost get Previous page link URL using below code.

```
this.router.events
.pipe(filter((evt: any) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized), pairwise())
.subscribe((events: RoutesRecognized[]) => {
  console.log('previous url', events[0].urlAfterRedirects);
  console.log('current url', events[1].urlAfterRedirects);
});
```

And I got previous page link url

[image]

But now i want make if condition for that URL in .ts file.

I try like below code for if condition.

```
if (events[0].urlAfterRedirects === '/resources/grid-view'){
      
}
```

[image]

And i got this error, So anyone help me make this if condition syntax properly.

Comment: Just look at you parenthesis and braces... Is it really this what you are asking??

Comment: other than having two unnecessary parentheses, as a best practice try to avoid these magic strings. A constant defined at the top of the ts file or in some proper place can be more appropriate.

Comment: I edit my parenthesis and braces mistake. but current is it right syntax to make if condition in current situation.

Comment: If you are damn sure that the string that you are checking will be exactly `'/resources/grid-view'` and not `'/resources/grid-view?somequery=something'` or `'/resources/Grid-view'` or whatever other mutations, then you are okay.

Comment: Are you sure your condition block is inside the subscribe block?

Comment: Please check i have edit my question. I think i making mistake in if condition syntax or statement.

Comment: @JigneshPanchal just move that condition block inside the subscribe block.

Comment: @KiranShakya But i want that condition on other place in this page so is there any way to store in *var* and make if condition.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232949/discussion-between-kiran-shakya-and-jignesh-panchal).

Answer (score 1):

```
this.router.events
.pipe(filter((evt: any) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized), pairwise())
.subscribe((events: RoutesRecognized[]) => {
  console.log('previous url', events[0].urlAfterRedirects);
  console.log('current url', events[1].urlAfterRedirects);
  if (events[0].urlAfterRedirects === '/resources/grid-view'){
      // You got it. Now you can redirect from here if you wish to.
  }
});
```

Reactive Programming is a programming methodology which works with the concept of streams of events. We can use pipes and other operators to bend or modify the stream and finally subscribe to these streams in order to get the final stream of data provided by different sources. To learn more about RxJs which is one of a reactive programming library, please visit: https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview

Going back to the question,

> But i want that condition on other place in this page so is there any way to store in var and make if condition.?

why you won't get the `events` parameter outside the `subscribe` block is because it is bound within that local block of the callback function. If you direly need that condition block to be somewhere else in the page, then you will have to wrap that condition block inside a function which accepts `events` as a parameter and you can then pass the `events` to it.

Something like this should allow you to have the `events` parameter somewhere else in the page:

```
this.router.events
.pipe(filter((evt: any) => evt instanceof RoutesRecognized), pairwise())
.subscribe((events: RoutesRecognized[]) => {
  console.log('previous url', events[0].urlAfterRedirects);
  console.log('current url', events[1].urlAfterRedirects);
  this.workWithEvents(events);
});
...
workWithEvents(events: RoutesRecognized[]) {
  if (events[0].urlAfterRedirects === '/resources/grid-view'){
      // You got it. Now you can redirect from here if you wish to.
  }
}
```